# Java Serialization, writeObject(Object obj) why not writeObject(Serializable obj)

Tags: java, serialization, jaxb2-basics

The method signature of `ObjectOutputStream`'s write method is

```
public final void writeObject(Object obj) throws IOException
```

As `obj` should implements `Serializable`  (know about markers). 
Why java developers do not write this method as

```
public final void writeObject(Serializable obj) throws IOException
```

is there any reason ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

writeObject is defined in ObjectOutput interface and its API says `The class that implements this interface defines how the object is written`. It means that theoretically there may be implementations other than ObjectOutputStream which may be using other ways of serialization which do not require the object be Serializable.

Comment: what are other way to serialize, apart from Externizalbe?